# Is there are a way to export asset to unity 3D or unreal engine with the applied shaders?

Tags: texturing, export, shaders, unity

In other words: can I use blender instead of substance painter or quixel in game development process, since blender support PBR materials, and the last version support PBR realtime render,and how?.

Comment: Short answer: yes, you absolutely can. Even shorter answer: yes.

Comment: how ? what is the possible way for that

Comment: The correct answer would be: It's hard to tell without knowing what you are referring to with the term shader and without seeing your material setup. Normal process is still baking textures - export model into rt game engine - tweak the material setups there.

Comment: @pycoder Aww c'mon man! You're not going to tell us HOW? Such a tease... Seriously, though, I have a hard time believing that either Unity supports Blender materials, or that Blender can export its materials to Unity shaders. If you know how to do this, you REALLY need to write an answer. We'd all love to know.

Comment: @Matt If you set up your material correctly in Blender (the textures are the same as Unity and the cycles shader interprets them in the same way as Unity's standard shader does), you can easily set up the material in Unity with the exact same settings and textures. I made a shader like this once to help improve my own PBR workflow...I will have to see if I can find it sometime. I don't think it's that revolutionary, so I don't know what you mean exactly.

Comment: To clarify my comment, I don't mean that you can just magically *export* a material from Blender, but the question was if you could use Blender instead of Substance Painter or Quixel for game artwork. Blender supports virtually everything Unity does with respect to rendering and Blender has all of the texture painting, vertex painting, etc. that you need. If you would like me to write a detailed answer with regards to *my* process, I will when I get a chance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask this the unity developers?

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you were talking about being able to magically export. That'd be pretty cool ;-) Even knowing that the settings are easy to translate is useful, though. I'd assumed there was just zero correlation between the two.

Comment: So.. you want to bake the Shading on the asset, then export to Unity, yes? Keep in mind that if you do this, the shading will remain static in Unity. If so, here's a couple guides that should help. https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html              https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html